# RegEx how to match this pattern

Tags: .net, regex

I am using the following regex to match the data as shown below. Only the 2nd and 3rd is matching not the first one. Can anyone help me know what am i doing wrong?

Basically i want to match the first and second and the last segments from the text.

Data:

```
306279 ABC TILT ROSE LVG
123456 ABC Chocolate PanL CH
123456 SSS Front Chocolate CH_Q
```

Expected Output

```
ProductNo   mattype     colorcode
---------   -------     ---------
306279      ABC         LVG
123456      ABC         CH
123456      SSS         CH_Q
```

My regex:
Regex:

```
^(?<productno>\d{6})\s(?<mattype>\w+)\s(?<body>(?:(?![A-Z]{2}).)*)((?<colorcode>[A-??Z]{2}(?:_[A-Z])?)?)$
```

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a c# question, it's a .NET question.  .NET regex engine.  Language is irrelevant.

Comment: I am writing this in C#. Please ignore the language and can you help me find the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
(\d+)\s+(\w+).*\s(\w+)$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/zD0hI4/1)**

Basing on your columns, you can have named groups like:

```
(?<ProductNo>\d+)\s+(?<mattype>\w+).*\s(?<colorcode>\w+)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thats great. Is it possible to strip _Q for the 3rd case when it matches? I just need to have either the last 3 character or if it has _Q then, strip out _Q and get it.

Comment: @MukilDeepthi I guess you can use `(\d+)\s+(\w+).*\s([A-Z]+)(?:_Q)?$`. Check it here https://regex101.com/r/zD0hI4/2

Comment: I like how you placed the debuggex.com image in the reply to help clarify the grouping. Thanks for sharing this resource.

Comment: @Paurian, thanks... debuggex is quite useful for displaying patterns

Comment: @FedericoPiazza thank you very much and as Paurian mentioned the debugged.com image is fantastic.